# Possible to use DateOnly with the DateTimeField control?

Tags: 2010, date-time

I have a `DateTimeField` control that I would like to only display dates with.  I tried setting the [DateOnly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.datetimefield.dateonly%28v=office.12%29.aspx) member to `true` but when I try to save the page that is using this it throws the following error:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.DateTimeField.set_DateOnly(Boolean value) +30
   ASP.MNCRFPPAGE_ASPX__1578019166.__BuildControlPublishedStartDate() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\8000\_catalogs\masterpage\MNCRFPPage.aspx:37
   ASP.MNCRFPPAGE_ASPX__1578019166.__BuildControlPageTitleInTitleArea(Control __ctrl) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\8000\_catalogs\masterpage\MNCRFPPage.aspx:25
   ASP.MNC_MAIN_MASTER__1063580889.__BuildControlPlaceHolderMain() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\8000\_catalogs\masterpage\MNC_main.master:443
   ASP.MNC_MAIN_MASTER__1063580889.__BuildControlMSO_ContentDiv() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\8000\_catalogs\masterpage\MNC_main.master:441
   ASP.MNC_MAIN_MASTER__1063580889.__BuildControl__control24() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\8000\_catalogs\masterpage\MNC_main.master:133
   ASP.MNC_MAIN_MASTER__1063580889.__BuildControl__control2() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\8000\_catalogs\masterpage\MNC_main.master:16
   ASP.MNC_MAIN_MASTER__1063580889.__BuildControlTree(MNC_MAIN_MASTER__1063580889 __ctrl) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\8000\_catalogs\masterpage\MNC_main.master:1
   ASP.MNC_MAIN_MASTER__1063580889.FrameworkInitialize() in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\9a65295e\deeb79d\App_Web_mnc_main.master_-1063580889.y606yxqr.0.cs:0
   System.Web.UI.MasterPage.CreateMaster(TemplateControl owner, HttpContext context, VirtualPath masterPageFile, IDictionary contentTemplateCollection) +1304
   System.Web.UI.Page.get_Master() +68
   System.Web.UI.Page.ApplyMasterPage() +17
   System.Web.UI.Page.PerformPreInit() +57
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1255
```

I found [this article](http://www.entwicklungsgedanken.de/2009/08/21/do-not-use-datetimefield-when-displaying-the-date-of-your-field/) which claims that it simply can't be done.  Is this correct?

Comment: Came across the same error in SP 2013. Seems the behaviour is same in SP 2013

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DateTimeField` uses internally a `DateTimeControl` on which the `DateOnly` value is set (passed through). But this internal `DateTimeControl` is not instantiated in the `CreateChildControls` method of the `DateTimeField` if the `ControlMode` of the `DateTimeField` is `SPControlMode.Display`.
(I had a look at the source code of the DateTimeField by decompiling it)

So try to avoid setting the `DateOnly` member of the `DateTimeField` if the `ControlMode` of the `DateTimeField` is equal to `SPControlMode.Display`.

Please note, that I did not test this solution...

Comment: Very interesting.  So if I want to have a field displayed in both edit and display mode would I have to create two EditModePanels that had the same field in it (one for edit and one for display) and then only set DateOnly on the edit mode panel?

Comment: I don't know your code to confirm your question... Maybe you could also get the current FormMode from SPContext.Current.FormContext.FormMode and set the value for DateOnly if SPContext.Current.FormContext.FormMode != SPControlMode.Display.

Answer (score 0):

Its kind of old but you can check the **solution** [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010general/thread/3a9fddcd-ed20-4a23-9b30-d08eb29f0f30/).

Basically, DateOnly attribute works fine for newly created layout. But if your layout is already published, you don't need to supply the attribute in designer. Instead:

- Go to the Site Settings
- Site libraries and lists (under Site Administration)
- Customize "Pages"
- Click the desired DateTimeField name under Columns
- Modify Date Only.

Hope it helps.